# What do I have to put in a software that uses open source libraries

Tags: licensing, jsoup, xstream, bsd

I've been studying java for the past couple months and I made a simple program that uses those Libraries:

- JSoup [MIT License]  http://jsoup.org/license
- XStream [BSD license] http://x-stream.github.io/license.html

Now, my question is, do I just make a License button in my program and paste there the MIT and BSD license (from the links above).
Also, do I need to license my program?

In the future, I would like  to release the program with ads as a closed source program. Will it be a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Well .. have you read the two different license agreements? Those provide information to answer your question.  LIcensing and what you need to do can be interesting (if not confusing) .. consider this story: http://opensource.com/law/14/7/lawsuit-threatens-break-new-ground-gpl-and-software-licensing-issues

Comment: I did read both of those license agreements and I've been reading things on the matter for a couple of hours. But, I'm still not sure if I only need to make an About button with the information of both those licenses , or will I need to do additional things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, do I need to license my program?

You ***don't need*** - but ***better do***! If you don't use a existing one (GPL, BSD, Apache, ...) make sure you know how to write a license!!

---

> make a License button in my program and paste there the MIT and BSD license (from the links above).

This is one way, you can also place the license into separate files (personal recommendation). Eg. create a license folder with a file for each library and it's license inside (or something else to make clear what license belongs to what lib).

In general you should make the licenses visible *without* the need to start your program!

**Examples:**

---

Create files for each license

```
<app root>
 |
 +- licenses
 |     |
 |     +- jsoup.txt <-- jsoup's license
 |     |
 |     +- xtream.txt <-- xtream license
 |     
...
```

---

Create a *single file* for all licenses

*3RD-PARTIES.txt*

```
3rd Parties
-----------

---------------------------------------------------------

This software uses '<name1>' - <description1> <version1> <year1>

<license1>

---------------------------------------------------------

This software uses '<name2>' - <description2> <version2> <year2>

<license2>

---------------------------------------------------------
```

---

> In the future, I would like to release the program with ads as a closed source program. Will it be a problem?

From the view of BSD / MIT this shouldn't be a problem.

---

**Documentation:**

- [Various Licenses and Comments about Them](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html)
- [What is Software licensing? - A quick guide to the basics of Software Licensing by Nalpeiron](https://web.archive.org/web/20110721052929/http://knol.google.com/k/jon-gillespie-brown/what-is-software-licensing/3v64x901bjfe2/2#)
- [The Challenges Of Software Licensing](http://omtco.eu/references/licensing/)
- [Open Source Best Practices](http://opensourcebestpractices.net/)